# Electric Power comes back when I open up warm tap water and then goes when I close the tap

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, water-heater

I've run into a electric power problem today that I can't seem to explain it.

The problem began when I opened up the warm tap water and I heared a sudden loud noise coming from the instantaneous water heater; I realised afterwards that power went out.

I noticed then that the kitchen (fridge + electric plates) still have power but everything else can't have it anymore even when I reset the breaker.

Surprisingly, I noticed that when I turn on the warm tap water, power comes back again **as long as the warm water is running** (when I close the warm tap, power goes out).

Is there a reason that could explain how power only functions normally when I switch on warm water?

Comment: Where are you on this planet? What make and model is said water heater?

Comment: Sorry I was on a rush. I'm in Germany and the device is called "Vaillant Durchlauferhitzer electronic VED E 27/7 Elektro-Durchlauferhitzer 27 kW" https://www.heizungsdiscount24.de/durchlauferhitzer/vaillant-durchlauferhitzer-electronic-ved-e-277-elektro-durchlauferhitzer-27-kw.html

Comment: Could this be that the main power path to the now-intermittent sockets failed, and now the heater (when turned on) is providing a back-door path for the sockets to get power? (Sounds scary...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Sorry I was on a rush. I'm in Germany and the device is called "Vaillant Durchlauferhitzer electronic VED E 27/7 Elektro-Durchlauferhitzer 27 kW" heizungsdiscount24.de/durchlauferhitzer/…

Your heater is a three-phase load, most likely with the heating elements connected between the phases.

I'm not an expert on german wiring practices, but my guess would be that your heater has developed a short circuit in one of the elements, said fault blew out the fuse supplying one of the phases and is now back-feeding said phase. Whether said fuse is your responsibility or your electricity suppliers responsibility I could not say.

I would advise against operating the heater until it has been inspected by a competent service technician and the supply fault has been rectified.

Comment: One easy thing to test is to turn off the heater **at the heater** or at least set it to the lowest possible temperature.  That way you can verify that  some electrical switch in the heater is enabling power.   I find it hard to understand, though,  how you can reset all the breakers and not have power to the other sockets unless some wiring blew out as well.   Be very careful  with everything on that circuit.

Comment: Somewhere here is an illustrated example of a backfeed across heating elements- I think it was a stove providing the 'return path' across the 2nd phase. But this sounds like that.

Comment: My guess is what has blown is a fuse (not a breaker) at the boundary between the electricity supplier and the customers installation. I can't be sure about germany but in the UK it's normal for the protection at the boundary between supplier and customer to be a fuse (for single phase) or fuses (for 3 phase).

Answer (score 3):

### You lost a phase

Germany often delivers 3 phases of power to a home.  That unit, being 27 kw, is almost certainly wired up 3-phase, and according to the spec sheets, it is wired "delta", phase-phase-phase with no interaction with neutral.

What's happening is when the unit turns on, it's having the effect of connecting the live phase(s) to the dead phases(s) *via the low-resistance heater coils themselves*.  This is having the effect of bringing the dead phase(s) back to life.

If you are using modern bulbs that accept 100-240V input, they are happy with the somewhat lesser voltage caused by this weird connection.

The "bang" was something in your service panel/consumer unit burning itself out due to a faulty connection, or possibly in the meter, or possibly at the service line from the electric company to your meter.  About half this territory is the power company's responsibility and the rest is yours.  Since the power company is probably free, I'd start with them.

The single most likely cause of this is overhead power lines, long having flexed in the wind, finally snapping at a connection from metal fatigue. The second most likely is an weak connection due to improper screw torque. This is such an epidemic in America they now make us use torque screwdrivers to set torque.

Answer (score 0):

### Do shut off the water heater via the circuit breaker(s) AND via the switch or thermostat at the water heater.

As already said by other authors, the interrupted phase is supplied by one or both of the other 2 phases when the water heater switches on (**backfeed**).
It could be a also multiple problem with a combination of shortcut(s) and low resistances between phases or phase to Neutral.

This could increase the voltage to a level that**destroys the devices** that are fed by this backfeed via the water heater, since the water heater's resistances are very low and the sum of 2 phases with 120 degree difference could be fed back.

The heater is connected to a 3-phase breaker that can only interrupt 3 phases alltogether, even if there is an overload on 1 phase only.

That breaker apparently did not trip - or the heater does not have a **combined triple circuit breaker**, but only 3 separate ones, which is against the standard/code.

Most likely an upstream fuse or breaker did trip, which is separate for all 3 phases.

**Do neighbours report problems** with some electric circuits not working? 
If not, the problem is within the own house/apartment.

The heavy main fuses/breakers upstream of the water heater directly at the incomer box of the supplier should give the downstream breakers the priority, i.e. a short in the wiring of the water heater should cause the downstream breaker(s) to trip, and not the main fuse/breaker.

Another 3 main fuses or breakers (for each phase) normally sits upstream close to the meter, and one of those could also have tripped.

Comment: It seems to me that neighbors didn't have issues as I was the only one who was visited by the electrician after I called the rental agency (I live in an apartment). He told me, after restoring power from upstream, that the heater was broken and that he will come back tomorrow with a replacement.